# What the intensity in a circuit when a generator is off?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Let the following circuit

[image]

I have to compute $U_{AB1}$ (i.e. $U_{AB}$ when $V_1$ on and $V_2$ is off), $U_{AB2}$ (i.e. $U_{AB}$ when $V_2$ is on and $V_1$ is off) and $U_{AB}$ (i.e. when $V_1$ and $V_2$ is on).

When for example $V_1$ is on and $V_2$ is off, does $I_2 =0$ or not ? i.e. By Kirchoff,

$$V_1=R_1I+R_3I_1$$ or $$V_1=R_1 I+R_3 I \ \ ?$$

After many tried, I always have confusion. How I can compute $U_{AB}, U_{AB1}$ and $U_{AB2}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$I_2$ is NOT zero when $V_2 = 0$. You have to replace the voltage source with a short ($R=0$) and not with an open ($R = \inf$). So when $V_2 = 0$ the circuit becomes a simple voltage divider.

So the whole thing will be something like this

$$U_{AB} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_2 // R_3}{R_1 + R_2//R_3}+  V_2 \cdot \frac{ R_1 // R_3}{R_2 + R_1//R_3}$$
where // means "parallel", i.e. $$R_2//R_3 = \frac{R_2\cdot R_3}{R_2 + R_3}$$

With a bit of math we get 
$$U_{AB} = V_1 \cdot \frac{R_2 \cdot R_3}{R_1 \cdot R_2 + R_1 \cdot R_3 + R_2 \cdot R_3}+  V_2 \cdot \frac{R_1 \cdot R_3}{R_1 \cdot R_2 + R_1 \cdot R_3 + R_2 \cdot R_3}$$

and finally
$$U_{AB} = \frac{R_3 \cdot (R_2 \cdot V_1 + R_1 \cdot V_2)}{R_1 \cdot R_2 + R_1 \cdot R_3 + R_2 \cdot R_3}$$

Please note that this counts $U_{AB}$ positive from A to B which is opposite from the arrow in the drawing.